# How to maximize the log likelihood of an AR(p) model?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, autoregressive

[image: log liklihood of an AR(2)]

How would I maximize this log likelihood function? And with respect to what? I think I should maximize it with respect to the coefficients $\phi$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you would maximize with respect to $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. The answer to your previous question is that $ \max_{\phi_1} \mathcal{L}(\phi_1, 0) \leq \max_{\phi_1, \phi_2} \mathcal{L}(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ since that for any $a$ and $b$ you would have $\mathcal{L}(a,b) \leq \max_{\phi_1, \phi_2} \mathcal{L}(\phi_1, \phi_2)$. An AR(1) model is equivalent to an AR(2) model where $\phi_2$ is restricted to the value 0. And adding a constraint can only lower the maximum likelihood. (You don't even have to look at what the likelihood function is to answer your previous question).

Comment: Thanks, is that true of any multivariate function or is it because the log likelihood function is monotonically increasing?

Comment: hmmm? the log likelihood function is not monotonically increasing in $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$.

Comment: The basic mathematical concept (for your previous question) is that the maximum (if it exists) of a function is always greater or equal to the function evaluated at any other point. That's why it's the maximum. If you're maximizing the log likelihood and are get to pick both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, the maximum is always going to as high or higher than if you set $\phi_2 = 0$ and only get to pick $\phi_1$.